# Find identical values from MySQL table from two columns

Tags: php, mysql

I need to filter only these table rows which have same values in x and y columns.

```
 _______________________________________
|
|    x    |      y     |      name     |
________________________________________
|
|   1     |      2     |     A         |
|______________________________________
|   2     |      1     |      B        |
|______________________________________
|   1     |      2    |     C          | 
|_______________________________________
```

The final result should be that I have A and C result. I need to filter these rows which has identical x and y values.

```
 _______________________________________
|
|    x    |      y     |      name     |
________________________________________
|
|   1     |      2     |     A         |
|______________________________________
 ______________________________________
|   1     |      2    |     C          | 
|_______________________________________
```

I' ve tried this code but I only managed to with one field.

```
select * 
from auto 
where x in (
        select x 
        from auto 
        group by x 
        having count(*) > 1
    );
```

Comment: In the example you give above it appears that all of the results would be returned.  Row B also does not match x and y.

Comment: X and Y is like coordinates I need to find the names which have same coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from 
auto a, ( SELECT x, y, COUNT(*) FROM auto GROUP BY x, y HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) b
where a.x = b.x
and a.y = b.y
```

will mark your other question as duplicate

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1, tablename t2
WHERE t1.x = t2.x
AND t1.y = t2.y
AND t1.primary_key != t2.primary_key
```

Comment: query returns incorect values